# R: how to automatically paste the file name when exporting a plot to PowerPoint with graph2ppt()?

Tags: r, export

I usually capture the file name and then import that file:

```
myInputFile = "G:/My Drive/dataFile.txt"

df <- read.delim(paste0(myInputFile), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I work with that file and then export it to csv using that same file name:

```
 write.csv(df, paste0(dirname(myInputFile), "/Output_", tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(myInputFile)), ".csv"),row.names=F,na='NA')
```

I also usually make a plot and I would like to easily use the same file name and export it to PowerPoint using graph2ppt().
It works fine if I simply enter the file name:

```
library(export)
graph2ppt(file="myPlot.pptx")
```

I cannot figure out how to paste the file name to graph2ppt() like I do with write.csv().

I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
graph2ppt(file = paste0(dirname(myInputFile), "/myPlot_", tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(myInputFile)), ".pptx"))
```

Comment: What's the output of `paste0(dirname(myInputFile), "/myPlot_", tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(myInputFile)), ".pptx")`? Can you create the name variable outside of `graph2ppt`?

Comment: I always create a plot in a separate window using something like `windows(width=5,height=4)`... As long as that plot is Active `graph2ppt` saves it as a power point slide if I type whatever the file name I want that power point to have. I have just recently learned from reading multiple comments how to paste0 the input file's name to csv that I export and it would be very convenient if this could work for `graph2ppt`. Sorry if I am not answering the question clearly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! This works!!

```
   graph2ppt(file = myInputFile)
```